# C# websocket local and remote endpoints

Tags: c#, websocket

Simply put, is it possible on an already-instantiated and fully open instance of an *outbound* `System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket` to determine any of the following:

- the local IP of the socket
- the local port (ephemeral) of the socket
- the remote IP (particularly important if connecting to a host *name*)
- the remote port (yes I get it, we should already know but the question is about what is possible)

Comment: Local IP and port you already know that and if you don't have it already the `ManagementClass` class can provide you with most if not all info about your local network.

Comment: @Franck the question is about getting this information from the websocket instance itself.  Opening a socket will involve using an ephemeral port so the local port will not be known at the time of instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No there is not any simple way to do this.**

The simple reason for this is that it's actually possible to create a `WebSocket` over any read/write stream, which may not be a network stream at all. So it doesn't really make sense to have such a property.

Perhaps it could expose the inner stream as a property, but that might break encapsulation. You could try making a [Github request](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues) for this.

As it happens, `ClientWebSocket` does contain a field `private WebSocketHandle? _innerWebSocket` from which you can use reflection to get the stream. Assuming that stream is a `NetworkStream` then you can get information from its `Socket` property.

Such a method would be very brittle to any library changes to undocumented internal design.